# comparing values in two lists in DROOLS

Tags: drools

I have just started using drools rule engine. I have two lists within a fact and want to the values inside them iteratively. i had tried a small thing but it did not work.i need to implement something like a nested for loop in drools. of the two lists, one is of type `String` and the other is of a user defined object.

```
rule "for the Handling Exception"

when
$billInfo : BillingInfo ( $except : exceptions , $handException : handlingExceptions , $rate : rate , $price : price);

  HandlingException ( $exc : exceptionValue ; $exce : this  )from $except
 exists ( String ( $handExc : this == $exc  ) from $handException)
then 

$billInfo.setPrice($price + ($rate * $exce.getDiscount()) );


end
```

above , except is a list of user defined and `$handexception` is of `String`.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to achieve is to check whether inside a BillingInfo you have at least one HandlinExpection ($h) and one String ($s), coming from handlingExceptions, such that: $h.exceptionValue == $s, you could do something like this:

```
when
    $b: BillingInfo()
    exists (
        $h: HandlingException(exceptionValue memberof $b.handlingExceptions) from $b.exceptions
    )
then

end
```

Hope it helps,